# Divs not starting from the top of container

Tags: css, html, centering

I have an issue with two divs horizontally centered next to each other: one of them starts from the top of the container div, but the other doesn't. I tried fixing it but only found solutions that weren't really pretty or correct.

Here's how it is:

```
<div id="missingSchoolProgram">
    <div id="missingSchool">
        <p>Votre école n'est pas dans la liste? Remplissez ce court formulaire afin de nous le signaler et qu'elle soit ajoutée plus rapidement!</p>
        <br /><br /><br />
        <form action="missingSchoolMail.php" method="POST">
            <p>Nom de l'école:</p>
            <input type="text" name="name" required="required" /><br /><br /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Signaler l'école manquante" /><br />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="missingProgram">
        <p>Votre programme n'est pas dans la liste? Remplissez ce court formulaire afin de nous le signaler et qu'il soit ajouté plus rapidement!</p>
        <br /><br /><br />
        <form action="missingProgramMail.php" method="POST">
            <p>Nom du programme:</p>
            <input type="text" name="name" required="required" /><br />
            <p>ID du programme (Ex.: 210.C1):</p>
            <input type="text" name="programID" maxlength="6" required="required" /><br /><br /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Signaler le programme manquant" /><br />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

The css for these divs is as follows...

```
#missingSchoolProgram
{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    padding-top: 15px;
}

#missingSchoolProgram form
{
    background-color: #e7edf1;
    border: 1px solid #ccdce4;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

#missingSchool
{
    width: 250px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}

#missingProgram
{
    width: 250px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And a jsfiddle so you guys can see the issue... 
http://jsfiddle.net/7taEu/1/

These things worked great before GoDaddy's servers messed up and my website was brought back to it's last save...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add: `vertical-align: top` to `#missingSchool`.

http://jsfiddle.net/7taEu/3/

Comment: How did I not think of this... Thanks alot! Works great!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to add a float:left; to the #missingSchool element.

```
#missingSchool
{
    width: 250px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7taEu/2/

Comment: That works, but floats cause a bit of trouble sometimes, so I'd rather use the vertical-align alternative. Thanks for the contribution tho!